# Find the position of a control relative to a cell in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

How can I find the position of a control relative to a cell in a grid?

Let's say my cell is in the `row=1` and `column=2`, what I would like to do is ideally:

```cs
var myTransform = myControl.TransformToVisual(???); //Refer to the cell in the grid
Point relativePosition = myTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

For now I was only able to get the position relative to the whole grid with

```cs
var myTransform = myControl.TransformToVisual(myGrid);
Point relativePosition = myTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

**EDIT 2**

To circumvent the problem I added a canvas on that cell and used

```cs
var myTransform = myControl.TransformToVisual(myCanvas);
Point relativePosition = myTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

but this is ugly...

Answer (score 0):

You can test it with this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Row: " + dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString() + " Cell: " + dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.ToString());
}
```

It just return the current cell and column index.

Hope it helps

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer, but I know how to obtain the row and column in the grid where the control is with GetRow and GetColumn; what I would like to know are the coordinates (x and y) of the control relative to the specific cell in the grid it is in. By the way I am using a Grid, not a DataGrid (I don't know if it makes a difference).

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry I have to pass then. Good Luck.